# How to fix KeyError of G.degree[0] when G comes from read_gexf

Tags: python, networkx

The graph read by nx.read_gexf can't use G.degree[n]. This will return a KeyError.

```py
G = nx.barabasi_albert_graph(2000, 3)
nx.write_gexf(G, "test.gexf")
G.degree[0]
```

return the degree of node 0

```py
F = nx.read_gexf("test.gexf")
F.degree[0]
```

----> F.degree[0]
KeyError: 0

How to solve this problem?

Comment: G.degree[str(0)] works, but why G and F are not the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When reading a `gexf` file, networkx will assume the node names are strings unless you tell it otherwise.  So your graph `F` has a bunch of nodes that are strings, not ints.  When you ask for node `0`, it can't find it because `F` has a node `'0'`.

```
G = nx.barabasi_albert_graph(2000, 3)
nx.write_gexf(G, "test.gexf")
G.degree[0]
F = nx.read_gexf("test.gexf", node_type=int)
F.degree[0]
```

Comment: https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.Graph.degree.html?highlight=degree#networkx.Graph.degree
The official example said G.degree[0] to get the degree

Comment: Ah, sorry - my comment was relevant for an older version of networkx.  I've updated.